# Orthogonality rules for a non-diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a non-diagonalizable matrix $H$ of size 2x2 with one nonderogatory eigenvalue $\lambda$. Therefore, we have that

$$Hu_0=\lambda u_0\quad \mathrm{and}\quad Hu_1=\lambda u_1+u_0$$ where $u_0$ is a right eigenvector and $u_1$ a Jordan right eigenvector.

Similarly, we have that

$$v_0^*H=\lambda v_0^*\quad \mathrm{and}\quad v_1^*H=\lambda v_1^*+uv_0^*$$

where $v_0^*$ is a left eigenvector and $v_1^*$ a Jordan left eigenvector.

How to prove that $v_1^*u_0\ne 0$?

---

**Original post in the quantum mechanics formalism.**

Consider a non-diagonalizable matrix of size 2x2, then (it will have degenerate eigenvalues and only one eigenvector)

So,

$H|\phi>=\lambda|\phi>$
and
$H|\phi^J>=\lambda|\phi^J>+|\phi>$

|> just denotes a vector and <| its' dual (bra-ket notation)

here

$|\phi^J>$ represents the associated jordan vector

consider that for $H^\dagger$

$H^\dagger|\xi>=\lambda^{*}|\xi>$
and
$H|\xi^J>=\lambda^{*}|\xi^J>+|\xi>$

here $\lambda^*$ represents complex conjugate of $\lambda$

How to prove,

$<\xi^J|\phi> \neq 0$

Comment: Your notations are those used in quantum mechanics, not those used in mathematics. In this regard, you may need to rewrite your question so that it is readable by people who are unfamiliar with the notations used in quantum mechanics.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with mathematical notations. I actually work in quantum mechanics that is why. Please suggest me some I will try and edit.

Comment: I can edit the post for you but I would need more details. What do you mean by the indices $i$ and $j$ here? There is only one eigenvalue $\lambda$ and so I am not sure how to interpret the index.

Comment: Ok now I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we can evaluate

$$v_0^*u_0=v_0^*(H-\lambda I)u_1=0$$

where we have used the fact that $v_0^*(H-\lambda I)=0$.

Now we can evaluate

$$v_1^*u_0=v_1^*(H-\lambda I)u_1=v_0^*u_1=\alpha$$

for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, where we have used the fact that $u_0=(H-\lambda I)u_1$ and $v_0^*=v_1^*(H-\lambda I)$.

Now we note that $u_0$ and $u_1$ as well as $v_0$ and $v_1$ are linearly independent. To see this, let us assume that $u_1=cu_0$ for some $c\ne 0$ and $u_0\ne0$. Then, we have $(H-\lambda I)u_1=(H-\lambda I)cu_0=0$ from the definition of $u_0$, which leads a contradicion.

Therefore the matrices

$$V = \begin{bmatrix}v_0^*\\v_1^*\end{bmatrix}\qquad \mathrm{and}\quad U=\begin{bmatrix}u_0 & u_1\end{bmatrix}$$

form bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and are thus invertible. Therefore, $UV$ must be invertible as well. Evaluating this product yields

$$VU = \begin{bmatrix}v_0^*u_0 & v_0^*u_1\\v_1^*u_0 & v_1^*u_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \alpha\\\alpha & v_1^*u_1\end{bmatrix}.$$

The product $UV$ is invertible if and only if $\alpha\ne 0$. This proves the result.